# GCC compiler error when extracting a char from a temporary stream

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, stringstream

I'm trying to read a single character from a stream. With the following code I get a "ambiguous overload" compiler error (GCC 4.3.2, [and 4.3.4](http://ideone.com/18gQq)). What I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    char c;
    std::istringstream("a") >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

Remarks:

- Visual Studio 2008 compiles without errors
- Other types (`int`, `double`) are working
- If I first create a variable `std::istringstream iss("a"); iss >> c`, the compiler gives no error

Comment: Actually, in your third bullet point, that's where you're finally _not_ creating a temporary variable.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thanks, I corrected the last point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The extraction operator `>>` for characters is a non-member function template:

```
template<class charT, class traits>
  basic_istream<charT,traits>& operator>>(basic_istream<charT,traits>&, charT&);
```

Since this takes its first argument by non-`const` reference, you can't use a temporary *rvalue* there. Therefore, your code cannot select this overload, only the various member function overloads, none of which match this usage.

Your code is valid in C++11, because there is also an extraction operator taking an *rvalue* reference as the first argument.

> Visual Studio 2008 compiles without errors

One of that compiler's many non-standard extensions is to allow temporary *rvalues* to be bound to non-`const` references.

> Other types (`int`, `double`) are working

Most extraction operators for fundamental types are member functions, which *can* be called on a temporary *rvalue*.

> If I first create a variable `std::istringstream iss("a"); iss >> c`, the compiler gives no error

`iss` is a non-temporary *lvalue*, so it can be bound to a non-`const` reference.

Comment: I remember that visual studio has extension which can bind rvalue to non-const lvalue ref , but that extension gives warning in VS which is ignored by asker I guess. Anyways +1 for such a nice answer :)

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: I don't get a warning for this program. I don't get a warning for `std::istringstream& ss = std::istringstream("a");` either

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: After your comment I compiled it again with no warnings! But after changing the warning level from `/W3` (which seems to be default) to `/W4` I got a such warning.

Comment: @ChristianAmmer: Okie doke. That's a shame. Silly MSVC. That code should warn on the _lowest_ level!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: it depends if you favor pedantry over pragmatism. The code works, it's just non-portable. I suppose there exist a specific portability switch equivalent to `-pedantic` that would diagnose those cases.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: What would be pragmatic is if Microsoft weren't encouraging people to write unportable code -- we're not exactly talking about crazy edge-case code here. As you can see from this question, it's led to this individual not knowing something that's quite basic in C++. Pedantry has nothing to do with this whatsoever.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Is it worth pointing out that binding a reference to an rvalue was legal in the original C++, but that it was removed because it turned out to be too error prone.  Pre-1990, so it's not like Microsoft hasn't had the time to catch up.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I personally consider that it is more error-prone now, sytnax wise. The inconsistency is jarring. 1. The const/non-const shism is annoying. 2. You can invoke a non-const method on a temporary, but cannot pass it as a parameter by reference --> but idiomatic C++ encourages free-functions! I would favor a more principled approach: either you can or cannot. For all its faults MSVC is at least consistent here. Though I personally favor avoiding taking references (other than r-value references) to temporaries.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Your personal considerations aren't in agreement with actual experience:-).  One may argue that calling a non-const member function on an rvalue should be banned as well---that would, at least, restore symmetry.  And one can definitely argue that overloading between members and free functions is not a good idea---it would be trivial to make all of the `<<` non-members, and it would be just as easy today (but not when iostream was being developed) to make them all specializations of a member function template.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Getting rid of `2.` is already a good step. As for 1., it was necessary to emulate operators, but now that we have r-value references operators we rewrite most operators to take advantage of it (when performance matter) anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The signature for the `operator>>` reading a `char` is

```
template<class charT, class traits>
basic_istream<charT,traits>& operator>>(basic_istream<charT,traits>& in,charT& c);
```

According to the language rules, a temporary cannot bind to the first parameter as a temporary cannot bind to a non-const reference.

Visual Studio 2008 allows this as an MS extension. Later versions will warn you that it is not allowed.